# NULL is always returned when I try to get contact or photo details from SMS message (Android cursor)

Tags: java, android

I'd like to get some kind of clarification and possibly even some insight into how this stuff is supposed to work, and how it actually works in Android development.

I am trying to do a few things. But to prevent this question from becoming too broad, I'll just limit it to one thing.

First of all, I'm trying to get:

1. A photo of a Contact from an SMS message.
2. The Contact ID, Contact Name and/or the Contact number from an SMS message
3. A Photo ID from an SMS message (if that's even how you access it).

I've tried about 20 different approaches,

The first one being the Android Developer docs (obviously). None of the code works. Out of the ~19 tutorials and none of the *many* samples I have downloaded and compiled work at all.

Right now, I am using the following code to try and get some kind of contact information from an SMS message:

```
while (cur.moveToNext())
{
    String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
    String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));

    long contactID = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
    String contactID = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id").toString());

    Message message = new Message();

    try
    {
        String number = getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
        String name = getContactName(getApplicationContext(), number);

        message.Sender.Number = number;

        String test = "";
        test = getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(("person")));

        message.Sender.Name = name;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.v("Sender ID Exception: ", exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

// ...
```

However, whenever I try to get "person", "contact_id", "photo_id", "_id", "id", or anything related to a contact, a contacts photo, etc, it always returns NULL, even if the message is *from a contact*.

I have set breakpoints literally everywhere in Android Studio, but breakpoints are not being hit anywhere, so I can't really debug anything properly.

I'd like to know 1 thing:

How do I get some kind of information from an SMS message which I can use to tell Android to give me more information about that contact, including a photo, name, etc?

The code above only allows me to get the message body. Everything else returns NULL 100% of the time.

And below is the relevant part of my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.app.tests"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

As you can see, I am pretty sure I have all the required permissions setup, such as `READ_SMS`, `READ_CONTACTS`.

Comment: please post ur logcat!

Comment: k0sh Logcat wasn't showing anything unusual until I pasted the code from mawalker's answer. I am not seeing a bunch of `W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000002` exceptions/messages.

Comment: That looks like you have an issue with your XML files not being able to generated properly into the R file. or something along those lines, Where exactly is that error popping up (this is why you should post logcat logs when there is errors.etc)

Comment: Sorry I am posting my logcat now

Comment: What Uris are you querying? It looks like you only have one cursor.

Comment: @fejd why would I need multiple cursors for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you 'inspected' the cursor before that while loop?

```
// This will give you the names of the columns returned.
int colCount = cur.getColumnCount(); // get number of columns returned

for (int i =0; i < colCount ; i++ ){ 
    Log.d("debuginfo","column: "+cur.getColumnName(i) ); 
}
```

This will give you the # of rows returned:

```
int rowCount = cur.getCount();
Log.d("debuginfo","rowCount: "+rowCount );
```

If you do this, you should have a better understanding of what 'results' are being returned by the cursor. The 'cursor' itself is nothing but an interator, and only 'points to' the values in the DB that are relevant. If the returned rows/columns are 0/0 then the cursor itself can't possibly contain anything useful for you, and would give you results like what you are seeing.

You're going to have to show us your query that obtained that cursor object.

---

You can get the methods I used above from the official documentation: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html